# Calling onClick function disables modal from showing on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a modal that appears when there is no JavaScript function in the onClick. I want the modal to appear when there is a function. The number of accounts selected is suppose to appear in the modal, which I'm attempting to show with a rerender.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("accountName").value
        )
      };
      function process() {
        console.log("proccess is firing");
        processAccounts();
      };
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="processAccounts" action="{!processSelected}" >
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:commandLink rerender="addedAccounts">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" onClick="process()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Selected Account(s)</button>
</apex:commandLink>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" onClick=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Selected Account(s)2</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="infoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infoModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="infoModalLabel">Opportunity Updated</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <span class="label label-default"></span><apex:outputPanel id="addedAccounts">{!numberOfAccounts}</apex:outputPanel> account(s) have been added to the Opportunity

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Clicking the button with a function]
Clicking the button with a function^^
[image: Clicking the button without a function]
Clicking the button without a function^^

What I see in the console when click the button with an onClick that has a value.

[image]

Comment: What are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @AdrianLarson added a screenshot of what the console outputs. I'm not sure why I get these errors when I call a button with onClick that has function value....

Comment: No reference to `availableData` in your snippet. Nor `jquery-ui`. We need to see more, methinks.

Comment: @AdrianLarson but availableData isn't being used in the second button that is working on calling the modal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `<apex:actionFunction>` you are not using the `rerender` attribute, so it reloads the page and you lose the modal.

Comment: It sounds like all that really needs to change is to specify a `rerender`, even if it's blank?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I think rerender is the key here.

Comment: @TusharSharma what do  you mean data modal?

Comment: @AdrianLarson adding a rerender to the apex:actionFunction did it

Comment: @TylerZika I am referring here bootstrap model.